# Error occurred while installing the application: Invalid <device> specified (Flash Builder 4.7)

Tags: flash-builder

im just fraking out with this problem.
Sometimes I'm getting this stupid error message, when I try to debug my mobile application:

> Error occurred while installing the application:
>
> Invalid  specified

The app wont be installed on the device.

I've tried:

- clean project
- restart Flash Builder
- restart Mac
- restart iPhone
- delete app from device
- trying a new workspace
- /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/bin/adt -devices -platform ios

Sometimes the message is not shown, but then the app even is not installed on device or I do not get a connection for debugging! (See Screenshot 3)
But in 99% I get this error message!

[image]

System:
Mac Pro (Late 2013)
OSX 10.10.3
Flash Builder 4.7
AIR 17
Flex 4.14.1 or Starling 1.6 (the problem exists in all projects)

Some Screenshots:

Screenshot 2:
[image]

Screenshot 3:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the Provisioning Profile & related Certificate that you're using are valid?

Comment: I've just found this link too, which mentions checking your iTunes version, and whether or not your device shows up happily in that, and the Xcode organiser, just to rule out any particular issues with your device and machine? https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1235474

Comment: @Ted : yes, of course! This configuration was running over weeks while developing.

I know this link, but it don't fixed my issue.

Comment: So you can build successfully onto your device from Xcode, and there's no connectivity issues with it when connecting to iTunes? If not, I guess it points toward a FB issue. Have you got any other devices (iOS or Android) you could build onto, just to double check if it is an issue with that device, or FB. Apologies if this is all obvious stuff you've tried before...

Comment: yep... deploying/debugging via Xcode works fine!
Flashbuilder also works fine with every Android device I tested!
Flashbuilder do not work with other iOS devices!

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help. There were a lot of different (often quite desperate sounding) suggestions further down that adobe forum post. Although sadly, the best sounding suggestion was the last one, _"I finally gave up on Flash/AIR development, which solved all my Flash Builder, Air for iOS and native extension problems."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching off all debug devices the problem do not longer exists.

But this should not the solution for this bug!